# Proof by contradiction or contrapositive

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove the following claim, using either proof by contradiction or contrapositive:
For $x, y \in \mathbb Z$, if $x + y$ is odd then either $x$ or $y$ is odd.

Would it be easier to prove by contradiction or contrapositive? Do both these statements below look correct?

Contrapositive: (restate): If either x or y is even, then $x + y$ is even.
Contradiction: (restate): If $x + y$ is odd then either x or y is even.

Comment: Does it matter that the original statement uses the word "either" x or y is odd?

Comment: This is a relatively straightforward proof by either method. I would suggest trying both methods for practice.

Comment: The contrapositive would be: If $x,y$ are both even or if $x,y$ are both odd, then $x+y$ is even. The proof by contradiction would assume that $x+y$ is odd and that either $x,y$ are both even, or that both $x.y$ are odd.

Comment: The proof of the contrapositive would be: Assume that $x,y$ are both even, then there are $a,b$ such that $x=2a$ and $y=2b$, then $x+y=2(a+b)$ is even. If we assume that both $x,y$ are odd, then there are $a,b$ such that $x=2a+1$ and $y=2b+1$. Therefore, $x+y=2(a+b+1)$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

For $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$,
Required to proof:
$$ (x+y)\text{ odd} \implies (x \text{ odd }) \vee (y \text{ odd}) $$
Contrapositive: Prove that the following statement is true.
$$ \neg ((x \text{ odd }) \vee (y \text{ odd})) \implies \neg ((x+y)\text{ odd}) $$
$$ \equiv (x \text{ even }) \wedge (y \text{ even}) \implies (x+y)\text{ even} $$
Contradiction: Prove that the following statement is a contradiction.
$$ (x+y)\text{ odd} \implies \neg((x \text{ odd }) \vee (y \text{ odd})) $$
$$ \equiv (x+y)\text{ odd} \implies (x \text{ even}) \wedge (y \text{ even}) $$
**Contrapositive** seems to be easier in this case.
Eg.
Since both $x$ and $y$ are even integers, let $x = 2n$ and $y = 2m$, where $n,m \in \mathbb{Z} $.
Therefore, $x+y= 2n + 2m = 2(n+m)$ is also even.
(*Please note that, when we push $\neg$ (negation) into the brackets, according to [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), we negate the propositions and conjunction/disjunction operators.

From Wikiepia:
[image: De Morgan's Law (Formal Language)]

Answer (score 0):

In this case both proofs would look almost the same, so they are equally easy.

*Contraposition*: prove that if both $x$ and $y$ are even, then so is $x+y$ (your restatement is incorrect: the negation of A or B is not A and not B).

*Contradiction*: [assuming that $x+y$ is odd] prove that if both $x$ and $y$ are even, then so is $x+y$ (and therefore get a contradiction with your standing assumption).

In other cases there is a bigger difference between those methods of proof, because the contradiction that you get may not be directly the negation of your standing hypothesis. For example, you could get something like $1<0$, etc.